# How to access static content through servlet in KARAF

Tags: java, jetty, osgi, apache-karaf

We are trying to access static content through servlet in OSGI KARAF. We don't have option to use spring here so we are forced to use servlets only. 
we are trying to do it by using default servlet of jetty.

```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet
</servlet-class>    
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

but i am facing an exception in logs while containers invokes defaultServlet object.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servletContext ServletContext@HttpServiceContext{httpContext=WebAppHttpContext{dashboard - 423}} org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext$SContext is not org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.initContextHandler(DefaultServlet.java:366) ~[?:?]

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.init(DefaultServlet.java:174) ~[?:?]

at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) ~[?:?]

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:637) ~[?:?]
```

Can I get any suggestions about how to access static resources on Jetty webserver on OSGI KARAF

Comment: There is already a `DefaultServlet` present in your webapp (on servlet named `"default"`), configured to use your configured base resource location, why do you feel you need to add another DefaultServlet?

Comment: okay do you mean I don't need to give servlet-class here and just giving default as servlet name should be good enough? you mentioned that default servlet is configured to use configured base resource location? can you please guide how and where do we configure base resource location?